# how to use a quoted string in a t_test function

Tags: r, t-test

I have a test datafile

[image]

I would like to run a t test.

This will work, which I already know

```
t.test(df_test$clin_value ~ df_test$trt_variable)
```

But I would like to do this:

trt_var = "trt_variable"

```
noquote(trt_var) # which gives me trt_variable
```

why I can not run this?

```
t.test(df_test$clin_value ~ df_test$(noquote(trt_var)))
```

How can I make this work?

I have to do this way, because I would like to change trt_var constantly.

Comment: `noquote()` just doesn't print quotes around the string in the console. It doesn't have magic powers to create a variable name unfortunately. You cannot use `$` with variable values. Instead use `[[ ]]`. Something like `t.test(df_test$clin_value ~ df_test[[trt_var]])` should work.

Comment: Thanks, it is solved, I tried [] previously, but not [[]].